# Generate Nested Tree Structure or Hierarchy based on parent child relationship using recursion - PHP

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I've been stuck in this since yesterday any help will be much appreciated. The situation is this: I have a table for navigation links with the following structure,
id | parent_id | text

In my scenario the parent_id may be null(no sub-menu) or any id pointing back to the table which will make the record a sub-menu of the parent. I've tried many different ways to execute this but with no luck, the closest scenario I came up with is the following,

```
// All navigation link results are stored in $data
public static function transform(array &$data) {
    $result = [];
    $search = function(&$array = [], $parent = null) use (&$search, &$result){
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            /** If the element has an ancestor */
            if($parent && $parent->id == $value->parent_id) {
                $next = $parent->children[] = $value;
                $search($array, $next);
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $parent;
    };

    foreach($data as $val) {
        $result[] = $search($data, $val);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

The function works fine and tracks all the ancestors of a certain link but in the next iteration is tracking all the ancestors of the next element(even if it was a child of the previous one) so it comes back with a lot of duplicated data. I came up with the solution to unset the iterated element from the array but for some reason, the element is still being used in the next iteration.
[Here is my current data](https://pastebin.com/raw/1pAU6J5y)

[Here is my current result](https://pastebin.com/raw/cYv6F0Se)

Comment: It may just need to have the `unset($array[$key]);` before the recursive bit (so move it before `$search($array, $next);`)

Comment: It's returning exactly the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple concept for faster search and to process one item only once.

- Create a temp array with `key as id` and `values as array of child ids`. Will use this array to process next direct childs. It would be a depth first traversal.
- Also set `id` as key in input array, so we can directly access whole node when required.

```
function generateTree($data){
    $arrChild = [];   // Store parent as key and its childs as array to quickly find out.
    foreach($data as $obj){
        $arrChild[$obj->parent_id][] = $obj->id;
        $data[$obj->id] = $obj;
    }
    
    $final = [];
    
    $setChild = function(&$array, $parents) use (&$setChild, $data, $arrChild){
        foreach($parents as $parent){
            $temp = $data[$parent];
            // If key is set, that means given node has direct childs, so process them too.
            if(isset($arrChild[$parent])){
                $temp->children = [];
                $setChild($temp->children, $arrChild[$parent]);
            }
            $array[] = $temp;
        }    
    };
    // Empty key would represent nodes with parent as `null`
    $setChild($final, $arrChild['']);
    return $final;
}

$final = generateTree($arr);

echo json_encode($final, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "navigation_id": 4,
        "parent_id": null,
        "text": "link 1",
        "icon": "",
        "url": null,
        "page_id": 4,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "navigation_id": 4,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "text": "link 2",
                "icon": "",
                "url": null,
                "page_id": 4,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "navigation_id": 4,
                        "parent_id": 2,
                        "text": "link 3",
                        "icon": "fas fa-ad",
                        "url": "https:\/\/google.com",
                        "page_id": null
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "navigation_id": 4,
                        "parent_id": 2,
                        "text": "link 4",
                        "icon": "fab fa-google",
                        "url": "https:\/\/google.com",
                        "page_id": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "navigation_id": 4,
        "parent_id": null,
        "text": "link 5",
        "icon": "",
        "url": null,
        "page_id": 5,
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "navigation_id": 4,
                "parent_id": 5,
                "text": "link 6",
                "icon": "",
                "url": null,
                "page_id": 4
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "navigation_id": 4,
                "parent_id": 5,
                "text": "link 7",
                "icon": "",
                "url": null,
                "page_id": 4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I hadn't thought of using temporary storage for the processed data and now I see the resolution of my problem.